# prove this $x^{m+1}|f^{(m)}(x)-x$

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ is polynomial with complex coefficients,such
$$x^2|f(x)-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}\cdot x$$
where $m>1$ be give postive integers,and define 
$$f^{(1)}(x)=f(x),f^{(2)}(x)=f(f(x)),f^{(3)}(x)=f(f(f(x))),\cdots,f^{(m)}(x)=f(f^{(m-1)}(x))$$
show that
$$x^{m+1}|f^{(m)}(x)-x$$

I try to use mathematical induction to prove.But there is no proof

Comment: It's difficult to use induction, because you would have to take with you the condition that $x^2\mid f(x)-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}\cdot x$ from one case to the next. The $m$ in there looks to me like it makes it very unpractical, perhaps impossible to prove the induction step.

Comment: Interesting problem. May I ask where it comes from?

Comment: Experimentation with Mathematica shows that if $f(x)=w x+\sum_{k=2}^m a_kx^k$ then $f^{(m)}(x)=w^mx+\frac{1-w^m}{1-w}\cdot \sum_{k=2}^mP_kx^k+O(x^{m+1})$, where $P_k$ are polynomials in $w$ and $a_j$.

Comment: @Inequality: I suggest to remove the acceptance mark of my answer, since a bounty question which is not already accepted might attract more user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attention [2016-11-20]:** This answer is **not correct** as it is based upon a wrong assumption
\begin{align*}
x^\color{blue}{m}\left|f(x)-\zeta_m x\right.\qquad\qquad m>1
\end{align*}
instead of
\begin{align*}
x^\color{blue}{2}\left|f(x)-\zeta_m x\right.\qquad\qquad m>1
\end{align*}

I have offered **a bounty** for compensation in order to support a correct answer to OPs question.

---

Let $m>1$ be a positive integer and $f(x)$ a polynomial with complex coefficients and degree $n\geq m$. We denote with $\zeta_m$  the following $m$-th *[root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)*
$$\zeta_m=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{m}\right)$$

> **Claim:** The following is valid for $m>1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> x^m\left|f(x)-\zeta_m x\right.\qquad\implies\qquad x^{m+1}\left|f^{(m)}-x\right.\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> with 
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(m)}(x)&:=f^{(m-1)}\left(f(x)\right)\qquad m>1\\
> f^{(1)}(x)&:=f(x)\\
> f^{(0)}(x)&:=x\\
> \end{align*}

We introduce some more settings for convenience. Since $x^m|f(x)-\zeta_m x$ there is a polynomial
$$q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}a_jx^j$$ of degree $n-m$ with
\begin{align*}
x^mq(x)&=f(x)-\zeta_m x\\
\text{resp.}\qquad\qquad\\
f(x)&=x^mq(x)+\zeta_m  x\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> **Approach:** The idea is to repeatedly apply (2) and so reduce $m$ in $f^{(m)}$ until we see that (1) is valid. In order to keep the calculation manageable we will consequently simplify expressions modulo $x^{m+1}$.

We do not go the shortest way, but add some intermediate steps to easier see what is going on and to motivate the claim (9) which is central for proving the answer.

> **Step: $m\rightarrow (m-1)$**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(m)}(x)-x&=f^{(m-1)}\left(f(x)\right)-x\\
> &=f^{(m-1)}\left(x^mq(x)+\zeta_m  x\right)-x\tag{3}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-1)}\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m  x\right)-x&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we substitute the RHS of (2) for $f(x)$.
- In (4) we note that 
  \begin{align*}
  f(x)&=x^mq(x)+\zeta_m  x\\
  &=x^m\left(a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-m}x^{n-m}\right)+\zeta_m\\
  &\equiv x^m(a_0)+\zeta_m&\pmod{x^{m+1}}
  \end{align*}
  This behaviour is also valid, when we consider compositions of $f$. This will become more obvious when we calculate the next steps.

> **Step: $(m-1)\rightarrow (m-2)$**
>
> We obtain from (4)
>
> \begin{align*}
> f^{(m)}&(x)-x\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-2)}\left(f\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m  x\right)\right)-x&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-2)}\left(\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x\right)^mq\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m  x\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad +\left.\zeta_m\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m  x\right)\right)-x&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{5}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-2)}\left(x^m q\left(x^m a_0+\zeta_m x\right)+\zeta_m x^m _0+\zeta_m^2 x\right)-x&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{6}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-2)}\left(x^m a_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2 x\right)-x&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we note the only contribution of $\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x\right)^m\pmod{x^{m+1}}$ is $\zeta_m^m x^m$ and since $\zeta_m^m=1$ we get $x^m$.
- In (6) we note the only contribution of $x^mq\left(x^m a_0+\zeta_m x\right)\pmod{x^{m+1}}$ is the *constant* part $a_0$ of $q$ multiplied with $x^m$.

> **Observation:** When looking at (4) and (7) we might see a pattern, but to be sure we add one step more.
>
> **Step: $(m-2)\rightarrow (m-3)$**
>
> We obtain from (7) and continue in the same way as in the step before
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(m)}&(x)-x\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-3)}\left(f\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)\right)-x\qquad\qquad\quad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-3)}\left(\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)^mq\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\quad\quad +\left.\zeta_m\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)\right)-x\qquad\qquad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-3)}\left(x^m q\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad +\zeta_m\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2  x\right)-x\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-3)}\left(x^m a_0+\zeta_m x^m a_0+\zeta_m^2 x^m a_0+\zeta_m^3 x\right)-x\qquad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{8}\\
> \end{align*}

We see from (4),(7) and (8) a pattern which we will prove next. In fact we could start the answer with the next step.

> **Step: $(m-k)\rightarrow (m-k-1)$**
>
> We show the following is valid for $1\leq k \leq m-1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(m-k)}&\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{k+1} x\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
f^{(m-k)}&\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\\
&\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(f\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
&\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)^mq\left(xa_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad +\left.\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
&\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(x^mq\left(xa_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad+\left(\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
&\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(x^ma_0
+\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^k x\right)\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
&\equiv f^{(m-k-1)}\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{k} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{k+1} x\right)&\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

> **Putting all together**
>
> With the help of (9) we can show OPs  claim (1).
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(m)}&(x)-x\\
> &\equiv f^{(m-1)}\left(x^ma_0+\zeta_m  x\right)-x\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{10}\\
> &\equiv f^{(1)}\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)-x\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{11}\\
> &\equiv \left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)^m
> q\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)-x\qquad\quad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{12}\\
> &\equiv x^m q\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)-x\qquad\quad\ \pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{13}\\
> &\equiv x^m a_0+\zeta_m\left(a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m-1} x\right)-x\qquad\qquad\quad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\\
> &\equiv a_0 x^m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \zeta_m^j+\zeta_m^{m} x-x\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{14}\\
> &\equiv 0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pmod{x^{m+1}}\tag{15}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (10) we apply the result  (4) of the first step to derive $f^{(m-1)}$ from $f^{(m)}$.
- In (11) we apply the main result (9) $m-2$ times to reduce $f^{(m-1)}$ to $f^{(1)}=f$.
- In (12) we apply (2), the representation $f(x)=x^mq(x)+\zeta_m x$.
- In (13) to (14) we do simplifications $\pmod{x^{m+1}}$ similarly to the steps before.
- In (15) we note $\zeta_m^m=1$ so that $\zeta_m^{m} x-x=0$ and we also use
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \zeta_m^j=\frac{1-\zeta_m^{m}}{1-\zeta_m}=0
  \end{align*}

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you did prove the claim only for functions of the type $f(x)=x^mq(x)+\zeta_m x$ and in fact this answer is only partial?

Comment: @inequality: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: Please can you answer my question?

Comment: Yes, but OPs condition was that $x^2|f(x)-\zeta_m x$ not $x^m|f(x)-\zeta_m x$.

Comment: @Nemo: Oh! Yes, you're right! I've misread the claim. Thanks for pointing at it. I've offered a bounty for compensation.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the space $A = t\Bbb C[[t]] = \{a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3 + \ldots \mid a_i \in \Bbb C\}$.

$A$ can be equipped with the composition law $\circ$ which is linear in the first argument
( $f \circ h + g \circ h = (f+g) \circ h$ and $(\lambda f) \circ g = \lambda (f \circ g)$ for $\lambda \in \Bbb C$).

Thus for any $g \in A$, we get a linear endomorphism $\rho_g(f) = f \circ g$.

If $g = b_1t + b_2t^2 + b_3t^3 + \ldots$, then $\rho_g(t^k) = g(t)^k = b_1^k t^k + \ldots$.
This shows that the "matrix" of $\rho_g$ is triangular (in particular, $\rho_g$ is compatible with the $t$-adic topology) and the coefficients on the diagonal are the sequence $(b_1^n)$.

Restricting modulo $t^{n+1}$ gives you a linear map $\rho_g^{[n]} : A_n \to A_n$ (where $A_n = t\Bbb C_{n-1}[t]$ has dimension $n$) defined by $\rho_g^{[n]}(f) = \rho_g(f) \pmod {t^{n+1}}$ whose matrix is simply the $n \times n$ submatrix in the topleft corner of the infinite matrix of $\rho_g$. Its eigenvalues are the $b_1^k$ for $k=1 \ldots n$.

Now suppose you are looking at a $g$ whose $b_1$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity $\zeta_n$.
Then $\rho_g^{[n]}$ has eigenvalues $\zeta_n^k$ for $k=1 \ldots n$, and since they are all distinct this is diagonalisable, and since their $n$th power is $1$, $(\rho_g^{[n]})^n$ is the identity of $A_n$.

Going back to $A$, this proves that the topleft $n \times n$ block in the matrix of $\rho_g^n$ is $I_n$, and so that for any $f \in A$, $f \circ g^{\circ n} \equiv f \pmod {t^{n+1}}$

Applying this to $t \in A$ you get $g^{\circ n} \equiv t \pmod {t^{n+1}}$

Comment: Instructive approach! Most of the creative work here is finding a proper framework to formulate the problem. If this is done the answer can be seen at a glance. Very nice! (+1)

Comment: wonderful proof !